# Python multiprocessing module freeze_support() line can be omitted error Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to experiment with multiprocessing in python. I have initially written this test code on a Ubuntu system and it exectued fine. When I try to run the same thing in windows, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Peri\Documents\Heatloss Project\OGI_u_value_module-master\test.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Peri\Documents\Heatloss Project\OGI_u_value_module-master\test.py", line 15, in main
    p1.start()
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 326, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 45, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 154, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Peri\Documents\Heatloss Project\OGI_u_value_module-master\test.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Peri\Documents\Heatloss Project\OGI_u_value_module-master\test.py", line 15, in main
    p1.start()
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 326, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 45, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 154, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\Peri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

The code is very basic, just two processes printing a text and exiting

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
    
def process1(text):
    return print(text)
    
def process2(text):
    return print(text)
    
def main():
    p1 = Process(target=process1, args=('Test1', ))
    p2 = Process(target=process2, args=('Test2', ))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    
main()
```

I am unable to understand what is going wrong in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to call one of the processes and then the other and don't do the
`p1.join() p2.join()` because that will just make the main program halt until the subprocesses finish.
This will work:

```
from multiprocessing import Process


def process1(text):
    return print(text)

def process2(text):
    return print(text)

def main():

   p1 = Process(target=process1, args=('Test1', ))
    p2 = Process(target=process2, args=('Test2', ))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the [multiprocessing Contexts and start methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

For my case, I had to utilize the context 'fork'

```
ctx = multiprocessing.get_context('fork')
work_queue    = ctx.Queue()
results_queue = ctx.Queue()
...
 workers = get_worker_processes(
    _process_data,
    (task_function, work_queue, results_queue),
    nproc=nproc,
)          
.....
workers = [
    ctx.Process(target=f, args=args) for _ in range(num_procs)
]
```

Follow the guidance given in the Python multiprocessing documentation for the link referenced. Notice the change in defaults.

> Contexts and start methods Depending on the platform, multiprocessing
> supports three ways to start a process. These start methods are
>
> spawn The parent process starts a fresh python interpreter process.
> The child process will only inherit those resources necessary to run
> the process object’s run() method. In particular, unnecessary file
> descriptors and handles from the parent process will not be inherited.
> Starting a process using this method is rather slow compared to using
> fork or forkserver.
>
> Available on Unix and Windows. The default on Windows and macOS.
>
> fork The parent process uses os.fork() to fork the Python interpreter.
> The child process, when it begins, is effectively identical to the
> parent process. All resources of the parent are inherited by the child
> process. Note that safely forking a multithreaded process is
> problematic.
>
> Available on Unix only. The default on Unix.
>
> forkserver When the program starts and selects the forkserver start
> method, a server process is started. From then on, whenever a new
> process is needed, the parent process connects to the server and
> requests that it fork a new process. The fork server process is single
> threaded so it is safe for it to use os.fork(). No unnecessary
> resources are inherited.
>
> Available on Unix platforms which support passing file descriptors
> over Unix pipes.
>
> Changed in version 3.8: On macOS, the spawn start method is now the
> default. The fork start method should be considered unsafe as it can
> lead to crashes of the subprocess. See bpo-33725.
>
> Changed in version 3.4: spawn added on all unix platforms, and
> forkserver added for some unix platforms. Child processes no longer
> inherit all of the parents inheritable handles on Windows.

I also found an attempt by some to resolve, and I think the resolution be better to inform the developer to set the context and start methods. Discussion found in issue at [bugs.python.org/issue42949](https://bugs.python.org/issue42949)

The problem for me started on MacOS Python 3.8 when I updated my conda env and python was updated to 3.8.10.

> envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main
> raise RuntimeError('''

some have had success with setting

`if __name__ == '__main__': __spec__ = None`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `main()` under `if __name__ == "__main__":` to run **python processes** as shown below. *I also got the same error to run **python processes** on **Windows** but I didn't get any errors to run **python threads** on **Windows**:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
    
def process1(text):
    return print(text)
    
def process2(text):
    return print(text)
    
def main():
    p1 = Process(target=process1, args=('Test1', ))
    p2 = Process(target=process2, args=('Test2', ))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

if __name__ == "__main__": # Here
    main()
```