# runtime error: Multiprocessing (python 3.9)

Tags: python

I am trying to run the code available here https://github.com/GDPlumb/MAPLE/blob/master/1-Accuracy/run.py but the following error occurs. Any idea how can I solve it

```
child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
```

main
in the
module :
if name     main freeze=support() --
"The ""freeze_support()"" line can be omitted if the program"
"return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, rnaxtasksperchild,"
"File ""C:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py"", line 212, in init"
"File ""C:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py"", line 303, return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Pro"
"File ""C:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py"", line 326,"
w.start()
"""C:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py"", line 121, in start lf._popen = self._Popen(self)"
_static
"in _repopulate_pool cess,"
in _repopulate_pool
File se
File re     """C:\Python39\lib\multiproce ssing\context.py"", line 327, in turn Popen(process_obj)"                 _Popen
"File ""C:\Python39\lib\multiproce ssing\popen_spawn_win32.py"", line 45,"

prep_data = spawn .get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
"File ""c:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn .py"", line 154,in get_preparation_data"
_check_not_importing
main ()
main
"File ""C:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn .py"",line 134,in *check_not_importing* raise RuntimeError ('''"
RuntimeError :
before
An attempt has been made to start a new process current process has finished its bootstrapping phase .
This probably means that you are not using fork to
the
your
start
child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:
if name     main reeze_support()
"The ""freeze_support()"" line can be omitted if the program"
is
"l.py"","
"File ""C:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\poo"
"line 326, in _repopulate_pool_static"
"File ""C:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py"", line 121, in start"
"File ""C:\Python39\lib\multiproce ssin \context. "" line 327, in Popen"

P.S: I tried adding `if __name__ == '__main__': pool = Pool(12) pool.map(run, args)`

Traceback (most recent call last): Traceback (most recent call last):
"File """", line 1, in  Traceback (most recent call last): Traceback (most recent call last):"
"File """", line 1, in "
"File ""c:\Python39\lib\rrultiprocessing\spawn .py"", line 116, in spawn_main exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)"
"File ""c:\Python39\lib\rrultiprocessing\spawn .py"", line 125, in main"
"File ""c:\Python39\lib\rnultiprocessing\spawn .py"", line 116, in spawn_main File """", line 1, in "
Traceback (roost recent call last):
"Traceback (roost recent call last): File """", line 1, in "
"File ""c:\Python39\lib\rnultiprocessing\spawn.py'', line 125,in  main prepare(preparation_data)"
"File ""c:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn .py"",line 236,in prepare"
_fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
"File ""c:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn .py"",line 287,in _fixup_main_from_path main_content =   runpy.run_path(main_path,"
"File ""c:\Python39\lib\runpy.py'', line 268, in run_path return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,"
"File ""c:\Python39\lib\runpy.py'', line 97,  in _run_module_code exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)"
"File ""c:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn .py"", line 116, in spawn_main File ""c:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn .py"", line 116, in spawn_main File ""'', line 1, in "
"Traceback (most recent call last): File """", line 1, in "
"File ""c:\Python39\lib\rrultiprocessing\spawn .py'', line 125, in main"

Comment: Please clarify code formating

Comment: I added this if condition if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(12)
    pool.map(run, args)    and the rest of the code is the same

Comment: Appears to be duplicate issue of [ref duplicate stackoverflow.com questions 61452513](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61452513/python-multiprocessing-module-freeze-support-line-can-be-obmitted-error-window/67846924#67846924)

Answer (score 1):

You must set the [multiprocessing Contexts and start methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

For my case, I had to utilize the context 'fork'

```
ctx = multiprocessing.get_context('fork')
work_queue    = ctx.Queue()
results_queue = ctx.Queue()
...
 workers = get_worker_processes(
    _process_data,
    (task_function, work_queue, results_queue),
    nproc=nproc,
)          
.....
workers = [
    ctx.Process(target=f, args=args) for _ in range(num_procs)
]
```

Follow the guidance given in the Python multiprocessing documentation for the link referenced. Notice the change in defaults.

> Contexts and start methods Depending on the platform, multiprocessing
> supports three ways to start a process. These start methods are
>
> spawn The parent process starts a fresh python interpreter process.
> The child process will only inherit those resources necessary to run
> the process object’s run() method. In particular, unnecessary file
> descriptors and handles from the parent process will not be inherited.
> Starting a process using this method is rather slow compared to using
> fork or forkserver.
>
> Available on Unix and Windows. The default on Windows and macOS.
>
> fork The parent process uses os.fork() to fork the Python interpreter.
> The child process, when it begins, is effectively identical to the
> parent process. All resources of the parent are inherited by the child
> process. Note that safely forking a multithreaded process is
> problematic.
>
> Available on Unix only. The default on Unix.
>
> forkserver When the program starts and selects the forkserver start
> method, a server process is started. From then on, whenever a new
> process is needed, the parent process connects to the server and
> requests that it fork a new process. The fork server process is single
> threaded so it is safe for it to use os.fork(). No unnecessary
> resources are inherited.
>
> Available on Unix platforms which support passing file descriptors
> over Unix pipes.
>
> Changed in version 3.8: On macOS, the spawn start method is now the
> default. The fork start method should be considered unsafe as it can
> lead to crashes of the subprocess. See bpo-33725.
>
> Changed in version 3.4: spawn added on all unix platforms, and
> forkserver added for some unix platforms. Child processes no longer
> inherit all of the parents inheritable handles on Windows.